# Removing class or background property without jquery only with css, is it possible?

Tags: html, css

This is my html:

```
<div class="class1 active">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is this. If `div 1` has a class `active`, I want remove either the div with `class3` or the `background property` of it, but I want to do it only with CSS, not using jquery. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.class1.active` and `background:none`

#### Snippet

```css
.class3 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px; /* demo */
  width: 100px; /* demo */
  border: solid /* demo */
}
.class1.active .class3 {
  background: none
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 active">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to fully remove the `.class3` set `display:none`

#### Snippet

```css
.class3 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px; /* demo */
  width: 100px; /* demo */
  border: solid /* demo */
}
.class1.active .class3 {
  display: none
}
.class4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 active">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3"></div>
    <div class="class4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the space but completely hide the `.class3` use `visibility:hidden`

#### Snippet

```css
.class3 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px; /* demo */
  width: 100px; /* demo */
  border: solid /* demo */
}
.class1.active .class3 {
  visibility: hidden
}
.class4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 active">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3"></div>
    <div class="class4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool @dippasl! Thanks.

Comment: You have to wait 6 mnts. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Labanino I updated with two more options. see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use "display:none" to totally hide div 3.

```css
.class3 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px; /* demo */
  width: 100px; /* demo */
  border: solid /* demo */
}
.class1.active .class3 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 active">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```